# Cursing the ground because of the imagination of the heart?

Tags: commentaries, adam, genesis-bereishith, evil-inclination

In [Genesis 3:17](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.3.17?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) G-d says that the ground shall be cursed because of Adam.

Later on in [Genesis 8:21](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.8.21?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) G-d tells Noah that He will never curse the ground again (since the devisings of man’s mind are evil from his youth) because the imagination of the heart of man is evil from his youth.

Does this mean that the ground was cursed in Genesis 3:17 because of the imagination of the heart of Adam?

Comment: Not seeing the connection. In 3:17 the curse is that the earth won't yield produce as easily, not that it'll be destroyed. Whereas the curse in 8:21 is referring back to the Flood.

Comment: I wasn’t referring to the curses themselves, but the reason @Meir , in both cases it the curses occurred because of mankind. So I was wondering if in the case of Adam the ground got cursed because of ‘the imagination of his heart’.